# How to convert 3 hourly data into hourly data?

Tags: r

I have a set of data for several stations that have 3 hourly and 1 hourly data frames. I have been able to seize through the data and separate the data into sets with 1 hr and 3 hrs. But I want to convert the datasets in 3hrs into hourly data. I do not need to estimate the missing data in between the hours, I can fill those as missing data, but I need to have a uniform data structure and all the other data in the database that I am using are already in hourly except those few stations.
I have included some data that shows the current dataset. [hourly dataset](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkyVR9N-vHoxsjuRYO0Tg7eammIe?e=wSGiNF). [3hourly dataset](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkyVR9N-vHoxsj0bzJJcCCBvP7RN?e=ZYcOWs). [expected dataset](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkyVR9N-vHoxsjzZy_DwwdPnpo6J?e=BxEy7Y)

Comment: Please remember to include a small reproducible example with toy data. This makes it much easier for the community to help you. Below I have provided a minium example with data generated in R.

Comment: Hi @Kresten. I am still a beginner in R and do not know how to go about this, but I have included datasets that shows the current and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my best guess of what you want solved with R and the `tidyverse`

I have read in your data. After row binding we expand the data to include the missing time points and join to original data for desired result.

```
library(tidyverse)
#read in the data
df1 = readxl::read_excel("df1.xlsx")
df2 = readxl::read_excel("df2.xlsx")

#fix names of one dataframe
names(df1) <- names(df2)

#create proper timestamps
df = bind_rows(df1,df2) %>% 
  mutate(ts = lubridate::ymd_hm(paste0(year, "-", month, "-", day, " ", hour,":00")))

#expand timestamps and station
expanded_ts <-
  df  %>% 
  tidyr::expand(ts, station)

#join for desired result
left_join(expanded_ts, df, by=c("ts", "station"))

## A tibble: 96 x 8
#   ts                  station  year month   day  hour    T2    DP
#   <dttm>                <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2014-08-01 00:00:00  450070    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 2 2014-08-01 00:00:00  450110  2014     8     1     0   295   259
# 3 2014-08-01 00:00:00  450320  2014     8     1     0   295   259
# 4 2014-08-01 00:00:00  450390  2014     8     1     0   304   236
# 5 2014-08-01 01:00:00  450070  2014     8     1     1   320   250
# 6 2014-08-01 01:00:00  450110  2014     8     1     1   310   250
# 7 2014-08-01 01:00:00  450320    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 8 2014-08-01 01:00:00  450390    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
# 9 2014-08-01 02:00:00  450070  2014     8     1     2   330   250
#10 2014-08-01 02:00:00  450110  2014     8     1     2   320   250
```

Comment: Hi Kresten, Thank you for the solution that you gave. I was able to use this without adding the variables, but as soon as I did, I started getting error messages about not being able to allocate vector of size *.Gb. Below is my present code


dat_stn2 <-dat_stn %>%filter(station %in% c(450320))
dat_stn3 <-dat_stn %>%filter(station %in% c(450070))
stn = bind_rows(dat_stn3,dat_stn2)
stn_mod1<- stn %>% tidyr::expand(station,year,month,day,hour,Temp,DP,WIDIR,WSP)

stn_mod1<- stn %>% tidyr::expand(station,year,month,day,hour,Temp,DP,WIDIR,WSP)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.4 Gb

Comment: Please load your data into R data.frames using `readr::read_csv()` or `readxl::read_xls()` depending on your input types. then row bind your data using dplyr::bind_rows to one data.frame. This dataframe can be expanded to the desired result

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy onward R-journey :) Please accept the answer then.